# How to call sbt environment variable while jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I am trying to create AWS lambda function through sbt. 
I have sbt plugin

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.gilt.sbt" % "sbt-aws-lambda" % "0.6.6")
```

I have an environemnt variable

```
'val env = Option(System.getProperty("myEnv")).getOrElse("int")'
```

I want to use this variable in the below sbt setting
and the following parameters under sbt setting against lambda name

```
.settings(
    s3Bucket := Some(s"bucket-name-resized-payload"),
    **lambdaName := Some(s"xxxx-xxxxx-$env"),**
    fork in Test := true,
    handlerName := Some("handler name"),
    roleArn := Some("arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/xxx_xx_xxxx_role"),
    region := Some("eu-xxxx-1"),
    awsLambdaTimeout := Some(60),
    deployMethod := Some("S3")
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, if the code runs at integration environment, then the function created should be Xxxx-xxx-int, in staging xxx-xxx-sta likewise in prod.
The sbt is built through Jenkins.
Now I am confused about how to pass a parameter
sbt -Denv := while code is building through jenkins
I don't want the same lambda name to be created for all environment.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two separate jenkins pipelines?
one for integration and one for production?
If that is the case then you can simply build artifacts by running `sbt -Denv=int` in one pipeline and `sbt -Denv=sta`

If you have single pipeline for both prod and int env then how do you decide what artifacts needs to be produced (either prod/int)?